# Induction, cardinality with natural numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, cardinals

Say you prove a statement $P(n)$ by induction, for all $n$ in $\mathbb{N}$.

Does the set {$P(k): k \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. P(k) is true} have the same cardinality as the set of all natural numbers? Is there a bijection here?

For some reason I can't find much. Google is pulling up a lot of "use induction to prove the union of $n$ countably infinite sets is countably infinite" which isn't quite what I'm asking, I think.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Do you mean "the set of natural numbers $k$ for which $P(k)$ is true"? If so, you told us that this was all of $\mathbb N$.  Or did you mean something different?

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  If not, I think it should be closed.

Comment: Voting to close the question.   If you can, please edit it for clarity.

Comment: thanks, i missed that. i suppose this makes sense- the context is proving there's a countably infinite amount of points relative to some other point, given some point-creation axiom and the property of distinctness.

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily.

Suppose $P(k)=P$ for all $k$ (in other words, the statement $P(k)$ does not vary with $k$). If $P$ is true, it is of course trivial to show that $P(k)$ is true for any $k$. Moreover, the set $\{ P(k)|k \in \mathbb{N} \land P(k) \}$ is just $\{ P \}$, which obviously has cardinality smaller than $\mathbb{N}$.

Of course, this is a very unusual case, and typically $P(m) \not = P(n)$ for $m \not = n$, in which case the function $f(k) = P(k)$ is a bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\{ P(k)|k \in \mathbb{N} \land P(k) \}$, and thus they will have the same cardinality in that case. But as I showed above, this is not necessarily the case.